# Make post Request with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'v been trying to make a post request with Javascript to slgg.de/api/login.php. It needs user and pwd as input and will the return the status a key and more to me. The response is then supposed to be processed on my external website. My current Code looks like this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.post("https://slgg.de/api/login.php", {
        user: "MyName",
        pwd: "MyPwd"
    }, function(data, status) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

edit: full code.

Comment: Change '=' to ':' its a javascript object.

Comment: Use `:` not `=`. Make sure to check the console for errors when debugging JS as it tells you what's wrong. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Looks like OP doesn't have an idea of DevTools. I am trying to find a good tutorial on it. Do you have anything that you recommend?

Comment: You missed a closing `</script>` tag after the including jquery

Comment: It really was the </script> tag XD

Answer (score 2):

They are objects. Objects are in `{"key": "value"}` pairs. Replace `=` with `:` and replace the `alert` with `console.log` so that you get a better idea of what's happening:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.post("https://slgg.de/api/login.php", {
    user: "MyName",
    pwd: "MyPwd"
  }, function(data, status) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but there is nothing happening.

Comment: @LeonBartz You will need to check the console for the output. Can you tell what's happening by pressing DevTools » Console?

Comment: I opend the console but noting is showing even after a refresh with the console open.

Comment: Ohhh... Did you include jQuery? This is strange. Can you post the full code? Maybe I'll try from my side and have a look on the same.

Comment: @LeonBartz Can you create a https://JSBin.com bin or add the full code to the question by editing it?

Comment: I did its not much because i need to get this running bevor i can do anything else.